# Why does rsync over SSH give me 10x the throughput of SCP?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, rsync, scp

1. `scp user@aws-ec2:~/file file`
2. `rsync --partial --progress -Pav -e ssh  user@aws-ec2:~/file file`

`scp` only gives me 200K/s, but `rsync` gives me 1.9M/s

I tested several times, all same results.

`rsync` uses multiple threads??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both of the protocols are based on SSH. And SSH [itself has some overhead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell#/media/File:Ssh_binary_packet_alt.svg):
[image: wiki]

SCP is really naive protocol with really naive algorithm for transferring a few of small files. It has a lot of synchronization (RTT - Round Trip Time) and small buffers (basically 2048 B -- [source](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/scp.c#L763)).

Rsync is made for performance and therefore it gives much better results and have more features.

The 10x speedup is specific for your case. If you would transfer files over the whole world over high-latency lanes, you would get much worse performance on the `scp` case, but on local network, the performance can be almost the same.

And no, compression (`-C` for `scp`) will not help. The biggest problems are the latency and buffer size.

Answer (score 8):

### RSYNC vs SCP

[SCP](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/scp.1.html) basically does a plain old copy from source to destination locally or across a network using SSH but you may be able to use the `-C` switch to enable SSH compression to potentially speed up the copy of data across the network.

[RSYNC](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/rsync1.html) transfers just the differences between two sets of files across the network connection, using an efficient  checksum-search  algorithm that automatically optimizes the network connection during a data transfer.

> ### [RSYNC](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/rsync1.html)
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> ```
>    rsync is a program that behaves in much the same way that rcp does, but
>    has many more options and uses  the  rsync  remote-update  protocol  to
>    greatly  speed  up  file  transfers  when the destination file is being
>    updated.
>
>    The rsync remote-update protocol allows rsync to transfer just the dif-
>    ferences between two sets of files across the network connection, using
>    an efficient  checksum-search  algorithm  described  in  the  technical
>    report that accompanies this package.
> ```
>
> <sub>[source](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/rsync1.html)</sub>

---

> ### [SCP](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/scp.1.html)
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> ```
>  scp copies files between hosts on a network.  It uses ssh(1) for data
>  transfer, and uses the same authentication and provides the same secu‐
>  rity as ssh(1).  scp will ask for passwords or passphrases if they are
>  needed for authentication.
>
>
>
>
>  File names may contain a user and host specification to indicate that
>  the file is to be copied to/from that host.  Local file names can be
>  made explicit using absolute or relative pathnames to avoid scp treat‐
>  ing file names containing ‘:’ as host specifiers.  Copies between two
>  remote hosts are also permitted.
> ```
>
> <sub>[source](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/scp.1.html)</sub>

Comment: In this case, the situation is a bit different though: He’s only copying a single file. (That presumably doesn’t exist yet on the remote end.)

Comment: @DanielB You don't think it could still be that **RSYNC** by default optimizes the data connection even for the one file and perhaps compressing the data during the transmission so less data chunks are actually sent down the pipe whereas the **SCP** without the `-C` switch doesn't compress data during the transmission of it down the pipe?

Comment: Neither compression nor checksumming are specified in his `rsync` command line. Of course the in-file delta algorithm is always active. It’s probably just that `scp` sucks.