# Poor SCP performance

Tags: networking, ssh, rsync, scp

I have dedicated server with gigabit internet access running debian.
At home I have retina iMac with gigabit internet access.

I'm trying to copy lots of data via scp and rsync. The problem is, that I'm getting transfer rate of 10 MB/s tops. As suggested by google search I've tried to change cipher to arcfour, but this didn't help at all.

What might be the cause and solution? I have over 2TB to copy...

Comment: This really depends on the properties of the network link between your server and home -- both may have gigabit connections to their respective ISPs, but that doesn't say much about the links between ISPs. Try pinging between them to check latency and packet loss (and maybe traceroute to find out how packets are getting back and forth). Also, try a transfer with something that runs pretty directly over TCP, like HTTP (without compression) or FTP and see what its throughput is like.

Comment: Wget via http gives similar poor result. Ping is 3 ms and traceroute is almost direct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does rsync over SSH give me 10x the throughput of SCP?](http://superuser.com/questions/1101077/why-does-rsync-over-ssh-give-me-10x-the-throughput-of-scp)

Answer (score 2):

In order to test real bandwidth between two machines you can use iperf tool. It is a client-server program, you need to install iperf on debian server and your iMac.

On one machine with ip x.x.x.x launch iperf in server mode:

1. **iperf -s**

On another just type:

2. **iperf -c x.x.x.x**

If the tested bandwidth is appropriate, then the problem may be related to throughput of disks, or some input/output causes of systems.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `iperf` defaults to an "upload" (client transmits to server) test, so pay attention to which end you set up as the client vs. the server, to make sure it matches the direction of your `scp` copy. If you want it to test one direction and then test the other direction, add `-r` to the arguments.

Comment: I get 101 Mbits/sec from iperf. Talked to my ISP and to technician at server location. Both saying that they are not limiting the bandwidth...

Comment: It is obviously that you reached only 10MB/s via scp, it's nearly 100Mbits/s like your channel is. Only one suggestion - check where you speed is limited, maybe, you need to clarify up/download speed of your provider. Sometimes the speed is not equal.

Answer (score 0):

You may have gigabit internet access but in most cases it is only gigabit on the download and not the upload so you transfer rate from one site to the other will be limited by the upload speed of the site you are transferring data from.

You can test your upload and download speeds using tools like http://www.speedtest.net/

Also take note of the difference between Megabytes (MB) and Megabits (Mb)
http://www.attinternetservice.com/resources/mbps-vs-mbps/

Comment: Speedtest on on server shows upload over 500 mbps. Download on client is over 800 mbps.

Comment: How long doesn't it say it will take to transfer the data?

Comment: At 500mbps it will take 10+ hours to transfer 2TB of data

Comment: Yes, but the real transer rate is under 100mbps.

Comment: Sounds like there maybe some kind of QOS that is capping the transfer speed somewhere between the two devices.