# Diagnose a network slowdown when scp and rsync locally

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, rsync, scp

I have a headless ubuntu box sitting in a closet that serves as my local media server. The process I've always used to get media onto it is to download media onto my OSX laptop, then scp the file across the local network. It's not elegant, but it works. Both computers are connected with wifi to an Asus rt-ac66, which can handle Gb speed supposedly.

The problem just cropped up when I tried to `scp` to the server a `931MB` file. Big, but not huge. `scp` gives me a nice readout telling me the transfer speed. It starts out at ~1.5Mb/s, then slowly drops all the way down to ~130Kb/s, that's a full-day transfer.

I'm a little at a loss on what tools to use to try and diagnose this problem. I've logged into the router, which has a "Quality of Service" tool that throttles some traffic, but that is turned off.

I know there's `netcat` and `telnet`, but I frankly have no idea how to use them to determine what the issue is.

What I've tried so far, mostly suggestions from [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/98858/how-to-find-the-bottleneck-while-transferring-huge-files-between-2-hosts):

Read and write speed seem fast on both sides, but when I do the `dd` piped through `ssh` things seems to slow down:

```
dd if=/dev/zero bs=1024 count=100 | ssh 192.168.1.109 dd of=/dev/null
me@192.168.1.109's password:
100+0 records in
100+0 records out
102400 bytes transferred in 5.272587 secs (19421 bytes/sec)
200+0 records in
200+0 records out
102400 bytes (102 kB) copied, 5.33353 s, 19.2 kB/s
```

That seems slow, but now what do I look for?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does rsync over SSH give me 10x the throughput of SCP?](http://superuser.com/questions/1101077/why-does-rsync-over-ssh-give-me-10x-the-throughput-of-scp)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately for this forum I don't have a *real* answer, the issue seemed to fix itself given time. If I encounter this issue again, I will probably just power cycle the router. This might answer the what to do, but doesn't answer the why, or the how to further diagnose.

The answer linked about doesn't answer the question, because `rsync` was exhibiting the same throttled behavior as `scp`.